# Grails 3 - i18n urls

Tags: grails, internationalization

I have a question how to handle internationalized urls in grails. I found a solution, but I am not fully satisfied with it.

I have a permission based autorization.

My solution is here:

GSP:

```
<g:link mapping="${message(code: 'companies.link')}">
```

mapping value is stored in i18n bundles.

Url-mapping:

```
    name companyProfilesCz : "/firemni-profily"(
            controller: "companyProfiles",
    )
    name companyProfilesEn :"/companies"(
            controller: "companyProfiles",
    )
```

Permmisions:

I need to have a separate permission for each internationalized url.

Is there a better way? Something that would not require to write separate permission and url-mapping for each internationalized url?